# Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have installed the latest version of python and PIP and while i was trying to install the snowflake-connector for my python. It threw an error. Tried several ways but couldn't solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Python Version: Python 3.8.5
PIP Version: pip 20.2.2

Error:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python
Failed to build snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: how are you installing snowflake-connector-python ? Install with a version number and give it a try again please.

Comment: I got the same problem, I am installing it with `pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wheel file for my Glue job.

Create a Wheel file or egg file .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

First, we will have to create a setup.py file for our package. Make sure you have the latest setup tools and pip installed.

$ vi setup.py

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "snowflake-connector-python",
    version = "2.2.7",
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

To get dependencies, we will have  to create a requirements.txt file and run the following:

```
$  pip freeze > requirements.txt

$ pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

To create the .whl file run the following :

```
$python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

To create the .egg file run the following :

```
$python setup.py bdist_egg
```

This will create a wheel file for our package.

Answer (score 0):

For windows snowflake supports python version 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7.
I had similar error, figured out i was using python 3.8.5. Downgrading to python 3.6 resolved the issue.

For more information [checkout snowflake doc for python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#python)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake now supports 3.9 and 3.10 as of July 2023.

Comment: Considering adding more context to this answer, perhaps with a code example or link to further resources.